# Structure constants of Lyndon-Shirshov basis of the free Lie ring

Tags: co.combinatorics, lie-algebras, free-groups, free-lie-algebras

Let $X$ be an alphabet, ${\sf Lyn}$ be the set of Lyndon words on $X$ and $L$ be the free Lie ring on $X.$ For $w\in {\sf Lyn}$  we denote by $[w]$ the corresponding element of the Lyndon-Shirshov basis. Then $\{[w]\mid w \in {\sf Lyn}\}$ is a basis of $L$ considered as a free abelian group. Therefore, for any  $u,v\in {\sf Lyn}$ there exist a unique family of integers $\{c^w_{u,v}\}_{w\in {\sf Lyn}}$ such that 
$$[[u],[v]]=\sum_{w\in {\sf Lyn}} c_{u,v}^w [w].$$

What is known about $c^w_{u,v}$?

Is there a way to compute them without huge straightforward computations?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120468/bracket-of-lyndon-words is closely related; I haven't heard of any "smart" recipes of computing those coefficients